# dynamic data manipulation in R

Tags: r, dynamic, replace

Suppose I have a dataset of units that change activity status from active to inactive across time. I would like to make a record of the switch from active to inactive each time the unit changes activity. A reproducible example :

```
UNIT <- c(100,100, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 300, 300, 300,300)
STATUS <- c('ACTIVE','INACTIVE','ACTIVE','ACTIVE','INACTIVE','ACTIVE','INACTIVE','ACTIVE','ACTIVE',
        'ACTIVE','INACTIVE') 
TERMINATED <- c('1999-07-06' , '2008-12-05' , '2000-08-18' , '2000-08-18' ,'2000-08-18' ,'2008-08-18',
            '2008-08-18','2006-09-19','2006-09-19' ,'2006-09-19' ,'1999-03-15') 
START <- c('2007-04-23','2008-12-06','2004-06-01','2007-02-01','2008-04-19','2010-11-29','2010-12-30',
       '2007-10-29','2008-02-05','2008-06-30','2009-02-07')
STOP <- c('2008-12-05','4712-12-31','2007-01-31','2008-04-18','2010-11-28','2010-12-29','4712-12-31',
      '2008-02-04','2008-06-29','2009-02-06','4712-12-31')
DAT <- data.frame(UNIT,STATUS,TERMINATED,START,STOP)
DAT            
UNIT   STATUS TERMINATED      START       STOP
1   100   ACTIVE 1999-07-06 2007-04-23 2008-12-05
2   100 INACTIVE 2008-12-05 2008-12-06 4712-12-31
3   200   ACTIVE 2000-08-18 2004-06-01 2007-01-31
4   200   ACTIVE 2000-08-18 2007-02-01 2008-04-18
5   200 INACTIVE 2000-08-18 2008-04-19 2010-11-28
6   200   ACTIVE 2008-08-18 2010-11-29 2010-12-29
7   200 INACTIVE 2008-08-18 2010-12-30 4712-12-31
8   300   ACTIVE 2006-09-19 2007-10-29 2008-02-04
9   300   ACTIVE 2006-09-19 2008-02-05 2008-06-29
10  300   ACTIVE 2006-09-19 2008-06-30 2009-02-06
11  300 INACTIVE 1999-03-15 2009-02-07 4712-12-31
```

When a unit's status goes from ACTIVE to INACTIVE this means the unit has been terminated.
Unfortunately the recorded termination date (TERMINATED) is invalid. A valid termination date 
is the effective start date (when STATUS == INACTIVE) minus 1 day following a switch from active
to inactive. In other words, the end date on a prior active record. In the case of unit 100, for
example, the TERMINATED date in row 3 is correct. The terminated date for unit 300, however, should
read "2009-02-06". The solution should be robust enough so that it understands unit 200 has two 
spells of inactivity and fills in accordingly.

I have no idea where to even begin on something like this in R

The end result should look like this:

```
   UNIT   STATUS TERMINATED      START       STOP
1   100   ACTIVE 2008-12-05 2007-04-23 2008-12-05
2   100 INACTIVE 2008-12-05 2008-12-06 4712-12-31
3   200   ACTIVE 2008-04-18 2004-06-01 2007-01-31
4   200   ACTIVE 2008-04-18 2007-02-01 2008-04-18
5   200 INACTIVE 2008-04-18 2008-04-19 2010-11-28
6   200   ACTIVE 2010-12-29 2010-11-29 2010-12-29
7   200 INACTIVE 2010-12-29 2010-12-30 4712-12-31
8   300   ACTIVE 2009-02-06 2007-10-29 2008-02-04
9   300   ACTIVE 2009-02-06 2008-02-05 2008-06-29
10  300   ACTIVE 2009-02-06 2008-06-30 2009-02-06
11  300 INACTIVE 2009-02-06 2009-02-07 4712-12-31
```

Comment: In your example data, both "INACTIVE" values for unit 200 need to also be corrected, right? Can you post the expected result from this mini example to eliminate any ambiguity.

Comment: That's right. But the termination date for unit 200 should be different.

Comment: something along the lines of: 
    for(i in 1:nrow(DAT)){ 
    by ID ... 
    If(STATUS[i] == "INACTIVE" & STATUS[i-1] == "ACTIVE") {
      TERMINATED[i] <- STOP[i-1]
     } 
    }

Where the [i-1] denotes the previous row. Any idea what the syntax is for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't spent too much time on this, but I think you should be able to do what you need with the following.

1. ***Convert your dates to actual date formats.***

   ```
   ## Use a real date format
   DAT[-c(1, 2)] <- lapply(DAT[-c(1, 2)], as.Date)
   ```
2. ***Create "groups" according to the combination of UNIT and when the STATUS column changes.***

   ```
   ## Identify the "groups" of "ACTIVE" and "INACTIVE"
   ##    by a combination of the first two columns
   RLE <- rle(do.call(paste, DAT[1:2]))$lengths
   RLES <- rep(seq_along(RLE), RLE)
   RLES
   # [1] 1 2 3 3 4 5 6 7 7 7 8
   ```

   You can see here that row 1 is from the first "group", row 2 from the second, rows three and four from the third, and so on.
3. ***Replace the current TERMINATED column.***

   By using the result stored in `RLES`, we can use `ave` to create a vector of the same length as the number of rows that contains the last STOP date by group.

   ```
   ## Use that grouping to create a partially corrected
   ##   "TERMINATED" column
   DAT$TERMINATED <- ave(DAT$STOP, RLES, FUN = max)
   ```
4. ***Fix the TERMINATED values for when STATUS == "INACTIVE".***

   By your description, the values here should be equal to the value from the START" column minus 1.

   ```
   ## Identify the rows where STATUS == "INACTIVE"
   IRows <- which(DAT$STATUS == "INACTIVE")
   ## Since you have a real date format, you can
   ##    simply use "-1" to adjust the TERMINATED date
   ##    using the value from the "START" date
   DAT[IRows, "TERMINATED"] <- DAT[IRows, "START"] - 1
   ```
5. ***Inspect the result.***

   ```
   DAT
   #    UNIT   STATUS TERMINATED      START       STOP
   # 1   100   ACTIVE 2008-12-05 2007-04-23 2008-12-05
   # 2   100 INACTIVE 2008-12-05 2008-12-06 4712-12-31
   # 3   200   ACTIVE 2008-04-18 2004-06-01 2007-01-31
   # 4   200   ACTIVE 2008-04-18 2007-02-01 2008-04-18
   # 5   200 INACTIVE 2008-04-18 2008-04-19 2010-11-28
   # 6   200   ACTIVE 2010-12-29 2010-11-29 2010-12-29
   # 7   200 INACTIVE 2010-12-29 2010-12-30 4712-12-31
   # 8   300   ACTIVE 2009-02-06 2007-10-29 2008-02-04
   # 9   300   ACTIVE 2009-02-06 2008-02-05 2008-06-29
   # 10  300   ACTIVE 2009-02-06 2008-06-30 2009-02-06
   # 11  300 INACTIVE 2009-02-06 2009-02-07 4712-12-31
   ```